# Composited container from std::set is faster than std::set itself?

Tags: performance, c++11, stl, iterator, stdset

I have made some composited container `Range` which accepts either a min/max range as a `std::pair` or a set of integers as a `std::set`.

*internally it saves a copy of the input by as `void *`*

This container supports `iterators` and I was curious how fast this container is compared to iterating just over the set `std::set`.

I made sure that I write every iteration loop in my test with the following policies:

- no post-increment (slower)
- make sure compiler is not able to fully optimize away the loops
- compare the same things

I have got the following timings:
[performance test](https://ideone.com/Mpv4eo)

**Speed Test

RUNTIME of Range: [Pair] : 13.0522 ms

RUNTIME of Range: [Set]: 272.54 ms

RUNTIME of std::set: 438.239 ms

RUNTIME of Range: Normal For Loop: 0.000175 ms**

**First**
I was suprised, and I hope you too, because why should my `Range` container be faster as the iterators of `Range` contain bot the iterator for the `std::pair` (simply a integer) and for `std::set`. And my implementation of `Range::iterator` actually forwards all operators to the std::set if the `Range` is a `std::set`.

**Second**
To you have any comments on the implementation of this to be efficient. Might there be a better approach?

Comment: This question would be a better fit at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note that your program runs forever on MSVC2013. That's because its RAND_MAX is 32767, but you try to insert 1E5 (unique) elements into the set.

Comment: I think this has to do with the copy you perform in `Range<Type> range(s);`. If I copy the set after inserting, e.g. insert in some `set<Type> s2;` then after inserting `auto s = s2;`, then the "std::set" loop is faster. This might have to do with locality, since the copy of the set will copy the elements typically in traversal order, while the insertion produces neighbours which have been allocated at very different times.

Comment: @dyp: nice =) I think this is correct:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With dyp's comment: 
the std::set is faster!

Speed Test ============================
RUNTIME of Range: [Pair] : 8.69353 ms
RUNTIME of Range: [Set]: 281.202 ms
RUNTIME of std::set: 220.367 ms // Recopied the std::set
RUNTIME of Range: Normal For Loop: 0.000196 ms